# Dealing with big data

Tags: performance, data, tools, big-data

I am on a project dealing with a lot of data in the form of images and videos (Data related to wind engineering). My requirement is to build a predictive algorithm based on the data I have. I have found many tools with which I can analyse the data where each tool has its own advantages and disadvantages. Big data being really new to me, I find it very difficult to choose a platform to start with. There should be other people here who should have dealt with similar situations.

- What criteria should I mainly take into account before selecting a
  tool for analysing big data?

I could update my question with the tools that I have found so far if that would be relevant for the question and my requirement.

**UPDATE**

Some of the Criteria that I have taken into account : Visualization, Interaction, Security, Data Access and integration, Speed of response, Integrated Data Mining, Pattern Matching, Ease of use etc. As you can see the list that I have made for the criteria comes from the extensive reading of different articles on the topic. But I can't narrow down the list nor find the individual contribution of these criteria in the various tools available for analysis.

Let me also list some of the tools that I found after googling : Knime, Statistica 2, Rapidminer, Orange, WEKA, KEEL, R and RATTLE.

On what basis could I choose a tool from a list of tools that perform similar tasks?

Comment: It would be really nice to know what was missing in my question to be downvoted? I would really like to add any relevant data that would aid in finding me an answer. :)

Comment: I think this question is at its heart a request for a software recommendation.  You seem aware that such a question would be off topic, and have constructed the question accordingly, but I have a hard time seeing how it can be answered usefully as constructed.  Yes, you are right about the criteria you should be considering, but the next question is how well the various tools meet these criteria.  Expert advice about the specific tools seems most useful at this stage.  Have you considered asking at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Can the question be migrated to softwarerecs?

Comment: How big are we talking?

Comment: atmost 1TB or more data per day.

Comment: Those criteria you listed are totally irrelevant for your question. The only criteria which matter are "what exactly are your requirements", "how good do the existing tools match those requirements", "what will they cost (including additional effort to adapt the specific tool to your case", and "can you develop a solution for a given problem in the required quality without a specific tool for less".

Comment: Still I am unaware what approach should be used to do the task in hand. So I thought it would be good to first find a tool for analysis of data;generate graphs and plots for predictive analysis and so on. I can't understand what tool can be chosen for the task in hand. :(

Comment: @ViniVasundharan You are doing things backwards.  Your first step is to clearly identify all of your requirements for predictive analysis.  From there you can gather any questions about how to fulfill certain requirements you are confused about.  Only then should you find a tool that can solve your problem.  Requirements present problems.  Tools provide solutions to those problems.  Nobody can help you pick a tool if you cannot define what your problems are.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. So i should first find an approach on how i could do the predictive analysis and then find a suitable tool that can aid in my approach. Repeating to make sure i got you right. :)